# Wordpress jQuery not working due to active shortcode in PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Here is the code-

```
<div class="container contact-form"> 
<p id="contact" class="pg-title contact"> Contact <br> 
    <span> <img class="narro-line" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/narro-line.png" alt="" /></span> </p>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>
</div>
```

jQuery plugins not working with including the shortcode `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false"]'); ?>` . But when I remove the shortcode from here then the jQuery is working properly. Where is the error?

Comment: I don't know what the error is...What does your console say?

Comment: There is no error to see

Answer (score 1):

try to use jQuery instead of $.

or if you want to use $ just define it in the on load function like below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(selector).event();
    //from now you can use $
});
```